# Have rows appear in table by date PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, echo

I have a table that appears showing a bunch of data one of the columns is date , I have been struggling for a while to figure out how to get the rows to show by the latest date, any help would be highly appreciate , I downloaded the script from phpjabber it is called mysql search table, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the examples first before you got some more minuses.

Your solution is here:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_order_by.asp

Comment: Please avoid link only answers as links might out date soon and so valuable information is lost. Instead add a small description of the core idea here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
order by mydate desc
```

in your sql